# Laravel 7: Service provider bind a class with a constructor parameter model

Tags: php, laravel

I've created a Service Provider with a class that has a `model` passed into the constructor.

The `model` needs to be a specific record based off the `$id` taking from the URL eg /path/{$id}

How can I use the requested `model` in the Service Provider?

An option is to pass the `model` into the execute method but for now I'll need to pass it into the construct.

**MyController**

```
  class MyController {

     public function show(MyClass $myClass, $id) 
     { 
        $model = MyModel::find($id);

        return $myClass->execute();
     }
  }
```

**MyClass**

```
class MyClass
{
   $private $myModel;

   public function __construct(MyModel $myModel)
   {
     $this->myModel = $myModel;
   }

   public function execute()
   {
      //do something fun with $this->myModel

      return $theFunStuff;
   }
}
```

**MyServiceProvider**

```
public function register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton(MyClass::class, function ($app) {
            return new MyClass(/* How can I use $myModel? */);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Hi! Did you try to do something like this? 1. In your register method: `$myModel = new MyModel()`; 2. In you callback function: `$this->app->singleton(MyClass::class, function ($app) use ($myModel){
            return new MyClass($myModel);
        });` Try it please and answer is it hepls you or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any value / reason to use a singleton here.

The service provider registers the singleton before your route is resolved, so there is no way to pass the `$model` from the controller into the register method. I would remove the service provider and do the following:

From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/container#resolving):

> If some of your class' dependencies are not resolvable via the
>   container, you may inject them by passing them as an associative array
>   into the makeWith method:

```
$api = $this->app->makeWith('HelpSpot\API', ['id' => 1]);
```

So in your case something like this:

```
public function show($id)
{
    return app()->makeWith(MyClass::class, ['myModel' => MyModel::find($id)])->execute();
}
```

Or shorter with the help of [route model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#route-model-binding):

```
public function show(MyModel $myModel)
{
    return app()->makeWith(MyClass::class, compact('myModel'))->execute();
}
```

Note that the argument names passed to `makeWith` have to match the parameter names in the class constructor.

Comment: Agreed, I would say that it's not a good practice to include any model object into a service constructor. `makeWith()` fixes this, but it's not an ideal solution, better put some more thinking into the class, and either make it stateless, and pass the model as an argument or call a setter.

Comment: @VladislavKryshtanovskiy I agree with you, passing the model to the execute method or setting it with a setter would be more ideal, I wanted to give the op an option to make it work with the given code, since he mentioned that he might change the implementation in the future.